# STDIN.ready? (crystal-lang)

Tags: crystal-lang

My current ruby commandline app uses `STDIN.ready?`. This permits me to capture complex keys such as Meta keys, Function keys, shifted-function keys etc.
I am not finding anything similar in Crystal.

While searching I found `STDIN.raw &.read_char`.
According to the docs, this should return a nil when there is nothing to read. However, I am not getting a nil. It seems to wait for the next key. The ruby code had a `$stdin.getc`.

My logic basically keeps reading STDIN as long as it is ready and accumulating key codes. The moment `ready?` returns false, the key is evaluated.

The logic NOW is:

```
c = STDIN.raw &.read_char
if c == '\e' # escape char
  loop do
   k = STDIN.raw &.read_char
   if k
     # accumulate k into a string
   else
     # evaluate string and return
   end
  end #loop
end
# rest of code if not escape.
```

Currently the `else` condition does not execute, so I am stuck in the `if` part. I don't know when to stop reading keys.

Previously, in ruby I had the second `getc` inside a `if STDIN.ready?`.

Earlier in ruby:

```
if c == '\e'
  loop
    if STDIN.ready?
      k = STDIN.getc
      accumulate in string
    else
      evaluation string and return code
    end
   end
end
```

EDIT: for me the correct answer lies in the link to 2048.cr suggested below in a comment.

Comment: If you know the maximum length of your keystroke, the technique used in the 2048 sample could be enough: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/master/samples/2048.cr#L39
`STDIN.ready?` basically checks if there's pending data on the IO, so reading all the pending data at once without blocking for more data should have a similar effect.

Comment: I will try this out tonight. If this works then it means that `read(bytes)` is non-blocking whereas `read_char` blocks. Yes, the maximum number of chars is probably four, for shifted Function keys, although in most cases less.

Comment: @JonneHaß thanks, your suggestion of 2048.cr works great.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, it is just a workaround if no correct answers here.

```
def handle_second_key(buffer)
  loop do
    input = STDIN.raw &.read_char
    buffer << input if input
    if buffer.size == 2
      if buffer[0] == '\e' && buffer[1] == 'q'
        puts "Right combination #{buffer[0].dump} + #{buffer[1].dump}"
        exit
      else
        puts "Wrong combination: #{buffer[0].dump} + #{buffer[1].dump}"
        break
      end
    end
  end
end

buffer = [] of Char

loop do
  input = STDIN.raw &.read_char
  buffer << input if input
  if buffer[0] == '\e'
    handle_second_key(buffer)
    buffer.clear
  else
    buffer.clear if buffer.size > 0
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The code you suggested from 2048.cr works fine for my cases. I have not checked for shifted-Fn keys yet, and its taken a lot of time to clear all the compilation errors. But it works, will update my question above.
If you post that comment as a reply, I would mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: This is not for the answer, i don't know how to do right. Just a little help for you porting code to Crystal. At the beginning of the learn the Crystal I also was not easy )